# Unable to populate dropdowns dynamically using angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

- I have 3 dropdowns, `A`, `B`, `C`.
- Based on *dropdown A* selection, *dropdown B* will be filled.
- Then based on *dropdown B* selection, *dropdown C* will be filled.


  I am able to achieve first 2 steps. But I am unable to achieve third point.
  [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mayankBisht/Xku9z/1195/)

Comment: what needs to be filled upon selection?

Comment: dropdowns should be filled with options, present in the angular controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
<div data-ng-app data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select data-ng-model="option1" data-ng-options="option for option in options1 " data-ng-change="getOptions2($index)">
  </select>
  <select data-ng-model="option2" data-ng-options="option for option in options2" data-ng-show='options2.length' data-ng-change="getOptions3()">
  </select>
  <select data-ng-model="option3" data-ng-options="option for option in options3" data-ng-show='options3.length'>
  </select>
</div>


function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.options1 = option1Options;
  $scope.options2 = []; // we'll get these later
  $scope.options3 = [];
  $scope.getOptions2 = function() {
    $scope.options2 = option2Options[option1Options.indexOf($scope.option1)];
    $scope.getOptions3();
  };

  $scope.getOptions3 = function() {
 var mergedOptions2=[].concat.apply([], option2Options )
$scope.options3 = option3Options[mergedOptions2.indexOf($scope.option2)];
  }
}
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nnn5px4b/)

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer, but when I select option 1 from dropdown A, then it's filling dropdown B with option 1 selection, similarly it should do for dropdown C. In your `working fiddle`, when I select any `option` from dropdown C, then again dropdown c is getting filled with some other values?

Comment: : Thanks a lot, it's working like  charm now. But how can I pass the last dropdown option to dynamically generate other dropdowns.You already helped me with problem, but now when I tried to integrate with todays code, it's not working, please help. `fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/mayankBisht/1o57qac2/2/`

Comment: Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2w0yp6d/1/) if this solved your problem http://jsfiddle.net/r2w0yp6d/1/ you can mark it as an accepted answer

Comment: Hi, again thanks for the answer, but it's not working as expected when I am selecting `women` - `w-top` - ``, `it's` showing `mens` options.
updated fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/mayankBisht/r2w0yp6d/3/`

Comment: Then you have to [Flatten out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10865042/5621827) second array check this working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r2w0yp6d/4/

Comment: Hmm, now dropdowns are working perfect, but `<select data-ng-model="option3" data-ng-options="option for option in options3" data-ng-show='options3.length' ng-change="onOption3Change()">
  </select>` is not correctly populating new dynamic dropdowns. It is always showing same dropdowns.I mean when I select option 1 from all the 3 dropddowns, then it should show 3 dropdowns because we have defined 3 for this index ` $scope.showDropDownOptions[0] = [2, 3, 6];`

Comment: what would happen if you select first index from first dropdown and second index from second and third one also i think you current problem is solved you can ask other so question for that

Comment: Hmm, actually there are 2 scenarios, first is for 3 dropdowns, you can understand them as *main category*, *sub-category*,*sub-sub category*.Second part is when user selects *sub-sub category option*, then dropowns will be generated.So when i select `option 1` from the last dropdown, then according to our logic this line should fire ` $scope.showDropDownOptions[0] = [2, 3, 6];`, so we are expecting 3 dropdowns with index 2,3,6 to appear.

Answer (score 0):

You have forget to call getOption2() function for fetching option3

```
<select data-ng-model="option2" data-ng-options="option for option in options2" data-ng-show='options2.length' data-ng-change="getOptions2()">
</select>
```

Fiddler
http://jsfiddle.net/Xku9z/1198/

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to achieve third point because you are trying to do that when dropdown A has a value, not B. If you add a new trigger on B, with the same functionality related to B, it will work.

Step 1: Add change trigger to your dropdown:

```
<select data-ng-model="option2" data-ng-options="option for option in options2" data-ng-show='options2.length' data-ng-change="getOptions3()">
```

Step2: Add a function on your controller to update options for dropdown C:

```
$scope.getOptions3 = function() {
    var key2 = $scope.options2.indexOf($scope.option2);
    var myNewNewOptions = option3Options[key2];
    $scope.options3 = myNewNewOptions;
};
```

I've updated your fiddle accordingly: http://jsfiddle.net/Xku9z/1196/

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would change your drop downs to call different functions. That way you aren't setting the third set of options before you need to.
Verified it works on JSFiddle.

Instead of..

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.options1 = option1Options;
  $scope.options2 = []; // we'll get these later
  $scope.options3 = [];
  $scope.getOptions2 = function() {

    var key = $scope.options1.indexOf($scope.option1);
    var key2 = $scope.options2.indexOf($scope.option2);
    var myNewOptions = option2Options[key];
    var myNewNewOptions = option3Options[key2];
    $scope.options2 = myNewOptions;
    $scope.options3 = myNewNewOptions;
  };
}
```

Use this...

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.options1 = option1Options;
  $scope.options2 = []; // we'll get these later
  $scope.options3 = [];
  $scope.getOptions2 = function() {
    var key = $scope.options1.indexOf($scope.option1);
    var myNewOptions = option2Options[key];
    $scope.options2 = myNewOptions;
  };
    $scope.getOptions3 = function() {
    var key2 = $scope.options2.indexOf($scope.option2);
    var myNewNewOptions = option3Options[key2];
    $scope.options3 = myNewNewOptions;
  };
}
```

And make sure you call  data-ng-change="getOptions3()" on your second select tag.